# Color grid like a progress bar?

Tags: wpf, colors, grid, progress-bar

I want to color part of a grid like a progress bar dynamicly.
Like one of the rows in the picture below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BKF4.png

Hope someone can help with a that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly what you can do is add a `<Canvas>` to the part of the Grid:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Canvas Background="Red" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Canvas Background="Green" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

If you are looking for a progress bar, have a look at [this](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-progressbar-control/) tutorial.

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly what i want, though i want to change the amount colored dynamically :) Will look at the link you gave to see if there is something like that in there

Comment: I don't think the link will help with that, what I suggest is looking at binding the RGB values to properties in the code behind.

Comment: The format is #RRGGBB or #AARRGGBB, with R, G, and B in hex, not decimal.